# julia how to quickly generate matrix by row from range

Tags: matrix, julia

How can I quickly generate matrix by row from range?

For example, given

```
my_example_matrix = [[1 2 3]
                     [4 5 6]
                     [7 8 9]]
```

How can I generate the matrix fastly by using range `1:9`?

Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quick in a way because no part of it allocates memory, so the length of the range won't matter.

```
julia> transpose(reshape(1:9, (3, 3)))
3×3 LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Int64,Base.ReshapedArray{Int64,2,UnitRange{Int64},Tuple{}}}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
```